# How do I decrease font size for desktop screens for the whole 'body'?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, fonts

I am just building one of my first websites and the most annoying thing is setting it up to look well both on mobile and desktop.

If I do it mobile first, the font is too big on desktop, if I do the opposite, the font is too small on mobile. It is responsive but not responsive "enough" if you know what I mean.

I would like to keep it mobile first and set it up so that it decreases the font size by 50% on desktop. I tried the following, which didn't work:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
body {
        font-size: 50% !important;
}
}
```

I know that I could use the `@media` with every div, however I don't like the results I am getting with that.

*Note: I am using 'vw' as size units.*

I hope there is a hack for that. Thank you!

*Later edit:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Voyage Sala de Nunti</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Sala de Nunti Voyage">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">


<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">





<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">




<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/5b698ffddd.js"></script>


<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate(1).css">


<style type="text/css">



@media only screen and (min-width: 970px) {
body {
        font-size: 10px !important;
}
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 1.18em;

}



.head-div {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;

}

  .head-div h1,
.head-div .h1 {
    color: #937b9d;
}
.head-div p {
  /*margin-bottom: 0.1em;*/
  font-size: 4vw;

  color: white;
  /*font-family: 'Playfair Display';*/
    letter-spacing: 0.4em;
    padding-bottom: -1em !important;

}
.head-div > hr {
  border-top-color: #d5d5d5;
}

.head-div {
  max-width: 100%;
}
@media screen  {
  .head-div {
    padding-top: 5em;
    padding-bottom: 8em;
  }



  .head-div h1,
  .head-div .h1 {
    font-size: 6vw;
    color: white;

    letter-spacing: 0.4em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    /*text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;*/
  }

  .head-div {
    background: url(img/sala-de-nunti-head2.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    height:100%;
}








.head-div1 {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;

}

  .head-div1 h1,
.head-div1 .h1 {
    color: #937b9d;
}
.head-div1 p {
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
  font-size: 4vw;

  color: white;
  /*font-family: 'Playfair Display';*/
    letter-spacing: 0.4em;
    padding-bottom: -1em !important;

}
.head-div1 > hr {
  border-top-color: #d5d5d5;
}

.head-div1 {
  max-width: 100%;
}
@media screen  {
  .head-div1 {
    padding-top: 8em;
    padding-bottom: 6em;
  }



  .head-div1 h1,
  .head-div1 .h1 {
    font-size: 6vw;
    color: white;

    letter-spacing: 0.4em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    /*text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;*/
  }

  .head-div-img-1 {
    background: url(img/sala-de-nunti-head2.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    height:100%;
}

  .head-div-img-2 {
    background: url(img/sala-de-nunti-1.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    height:100%;
}









.btn-transparent {
    background: transparent; 
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;

    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

.btn-white {
    background: white; 
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: #937b98;
    font-weight: 250;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}


.description {
    background-color: #937b98;
    color: white;

}

.large {
    padding-top: 3.5em;
    padding-bottom: 3em;




}

h1.large {

    color: white;

    font-size: 4vw;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}




@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.present {

    color: white;
    font-weight: 100 !important;
    font-size: 4vw;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    padding-top: 4vw;
    padding-bottom: 4vw;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
.md-sc {
    color: white;

    font-size: 4vw;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

}
.large-white {
    padding-top: 3.5em;
    padding-bottom: 3em;

    padding-right: 2em;

}

#title {
    color: #937b98;

    font-size: 4vw;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display';
}

#text {
    color: #937b98;

    font-size: 4vw;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    color: #000;

}


h1#title {
    padding-bottom: 1vw;
}

.icon-service {
    color: #937b98;

    font-size: 3vw;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    color: #000;


}


.white-header {

    padding-top: 1.5em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.white-text{

    font-size: 2vw;
    color: #937b98;
}

.icon-padding {
    padding: 1em;

}

/*CAROUSEL*/

.pad-bot {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.padd-bott {
    padding-bottom: 4em;
}

.contact {
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;

    color: grey;

}

.padd-top

{
    padding-top: 11em;
}
#outer::before, #outer::after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    height: 10%;
}
#inner {
    height: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}



@media (min-width: 1200px) {
 .margin-correct {
        margin-left: -7em;
}
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
.large-div {
    height: 10em;
}
}

.serv {
    font-size: 9vw;
    line-height: 3.5vw;
}


.vertical-allign-middle {
     vertical-align: middle !important;
     padding-top: 40%;
}


.text {
    font-size: 4vw;
}

.light-weight {
    font-weight: 100 !important;
}


</style>



</head>



















<body>

    <!-- Navbar -->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top  my-own-style" id="my-navbar">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">


                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" style="font-size: 3vw;">Voyage</a>
            </div>

        </div> 

</nav> 

<br> 




<div class="head-div1 head-div-img-1 padd-top pad-bot vertical-allign-middle">
        <!-- <div class="container text-center vertical-align-middle">

            <p style="font-weight: 200">sala de nunti</p>
            <h1 style="font-weight: 200">VOYAGE</h1>


            <button type="button" class="btn  btn-lg btn-white">
             Informatii la 069137950
            </button> -->


        </div>

</div>


<div class="container-fluid description">
    <div class="container large present text-center"><p style="font-size: 4vw">Voyage este un restaurant destinat exclusiv nuntilor, care ofera, pe langa locatia rafinata si festinul culinar, tot ce aveti nevoie pentru un eveniment unic.<p></div>
</div>


<!-- triple div 1 -->


<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <div class="container large-white">
    <h1 id="title" style="font-size: 6vw;">Vrei o atmosferă elegantă și festivă?
</h1>
    <p id="text">Voyage este locul în care atitudinea se intersectează cu aptitudinea, în care organizarea întâlnește perfecțiunea, iar flexibilitatea generează satisfacția.<p></div>
</div>





<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>


    </ol>


    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/slider/sala-de-nunti-slider-1.png" alt="saladenunti" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/slider/sala-de-nunti-slider-2.png" alt="saladenunti" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/slider/sala-de-nunti-slider-3.png" alt="saladenunti" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

    </div>




</div>



<!-- triple div 2 -->



<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <div class="container large-white">
    <h1 id="title" style="font-size: 6vw;">Vrei o masă bogată, cu cele mai gustoase preparate?
</h1>
    <p id="text">Voyage rămâne restaurantul cu cele mai gustoase preparate de nuntă, care menține și prețurile "pământești". Prestigiul pe care l-am castigat de-a lungul anilor ne obligă să menținem întotdeauna cele mai ridicate standarde în tot ceea ce facem, cuvântul nostru de ordine fiind “calitate”, atât a preparatelor cât și a serviciilor și respectarea promisiunii făcute!<p></div>
</div>





<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>


    </ol>


    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/slider/sala-de-nunti-slider-4.png" alt="saladenunti" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/slider/sala-de-nunti-slider-5.png" alt="saladenunti" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/slider/sala-de-nunti-slider-6.png" alt="saladenunti" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

    </div>




</div>


<!-- triple div 3 -->



<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <div class="container large-white">
    <h1 id="title" style="font-size: 6vw;">Vrei să-ți oficiezi înscrierea în sânul naturii?
</h1>
    <p id="text">Aici orice eveniment ia amploarea unuia de poveste! Pe lângă meniul bogat și variat, aveți posibilitatea oficerii căsătoriei civile în grădina privată cu arcă special decorată în acest scop. Iar oaspeții dornici de relaxare se pot delecta sub adierea sălciilor la terasele discret amplasate.<p></div>
</div>





<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>


    </ol>


    <div class="carousel-inner pad-bot large-div">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/slider/sala-de-nunti-slider-7.png" alt="saladenunti" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/slider/sala-de-nunti-slider-8.png" alt="saladenunti" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/slider/sala-de-nunti-slider-9.png" alt="saladenunti" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

    </div>




</div>




<!-- 

<div class="container-fluid text-center description padd-bott">


    <div class="container large"><p>Te asteptam la Voayge. Capacitatea restaurantului este de 190 de persoane, iar prețul unui meniu mediu - 700 de lei<p></div>

    <button type="button" class="btn  btn-lg btn-transparent">
             Informatii la 069137950
            </button>
</div>

 -->








<div class="container-fluid text-center ">
    <div class="container"><h1 class="white-header light-weight" style="font-size: 6vw">În 2018 Voyage vă oferă gratuit<h1></div>


        <div class="row serv">

            <div class="col-md-4 icon-service icon-padding"><span class="white-text"><p style="font-size: 4vw"><i class="fa fa-pagelines" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Accesorii decorative</p></span></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 icon-service icon-padding"><span class="white-text"><p style="font-size: 4vw"><i class="fa fa-wifi" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>WiFi internet</p></span></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 icon-service icon-padding"><span class="white-text"><span class="white-text"><p style="font-size: 4vw"><i class="fa fa-female" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Camera pentru mireasă</p></span></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 icon-service icon-padding"><span class="white-text"><span class="white-text"><p style="font-size: 4vw"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Terasă pentru ceremonia civilă</p></span></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 icon-service icon-padding"><span class="white-text"><p style="font-size: 4vw"><i class="fa fa-handshake-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Insulă pentru întâmpinarea oaspeților</p></span></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 icon-service icon-padding"><span class="white-text"><p style="font-size: 4vw"><i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>"Cartea Nunții Perfecte" Mindy Weiss</p></span></div>
            <div class="col-md-12 icon-service icon-padding"><span class="white-text"><p style="font-size: 4vw"><i class="fa fa-car" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Parcare supravegheată</p></span></div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="container-fluid text-center pad-bot">
    <div class="container"><h1 class="white-header light-weight" style="font-size: 6vw">Cadoul restaurantului de la 150 de invitati<h1></div>


        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-6 icon-service icon-padding"><span class="white-text"><p style="font-size: 4vw"><i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Consum nelimitat ceai si cafea naturala</p></span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 icon-service icon-padding"><span class="white-text"><p style="font-size: 4vw"><i class="fa fa-cutlery" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Meniu pentru echipa artistica</p></span></div>


        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="container-fluid description">
    <div class="container large present text-center"><p style="font-size: 4vw">Capacitatea sălii acoperă evenimente de diverse dimensiuni, de la 80 pana la 190 de invitați. Acordăm atenţie fiecărui detaliu, astfel încât ziua nunții să se desfăşoare întocmai precum îți imaginezi. Trăiește și tu experiența Voyage!<p></div>
</div>



<div class="head-div1 head-div-img-2 padd-top pad-bot">
        <div class="container text-center">


        </div>

</div>






<div class="contacts container-fluid contact">

        <div class="row">

             <div class="col-sm-3"><p style="font-size: 1.5vw"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Voyage-Sala-de-Nunti-157967211008964/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>Pagina noastra de Facebook</p></div>
             <div class="col-sm-3"><p style="font-size: 1.5vw"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>Telefon: 0 691 37 950</p></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><p style="font-size: 1.5vw"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>Sos. Chisinau-Hances. km10</p></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><p style="font-size: 1.5vw"><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Voyage/@46.9595993,28.749311,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xd4545e11fc7d2e95?sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilx9KomLrTAhWqNJoKHcMkAC8Q_BIIkAEwDg" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-location-arrow fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" ></i></a>Pe Google Maps</p></div>



        </div>

</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js
"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




</body>
</html>
```

**SOLUTION:**

So while I didn't find a hack to magically decrease all the font by 50% from the mobile version when it is on desktop, I did break the text in 4 classes ('extra-large, large, medium, small') and for each of them I specified the respective 'font-size' for two screen size (smaller than 1000px and larger than 1001).

It looks something like that:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1001px){

.extra-large {
        font-size: 6vw !important;
}

}

@media only screen and (min-width:1000px){

.extra-large {
        font-size: 3vw !important;
}

}
```

Comment: make min-width 768px

Comment: Thank you, I did, everything stays the same.

Comment: did you try with increasing the font size greater than 50%?

Comment: I was hoping the 50% would make it 50% of the original size (the one for the mobile). I can see how that's not the case.

Comment: You are missing the viewport meta tag. without viewport tag, media query doesnot work. <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

Comment: than you, I'll add that ine

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1000px){

body {
        font-size: 20px !important;
}

}

@media only screen and (min-width:1001px){

body {
        font-size: 40px !important;
}

}
```

**Maybe some DIV's settings are overwritten by other CSS settings so add this if it dosn't work** (in the media screen tag).

```
body, #somediv {
        font-size: 40px !important;
}
```

*You can also try the bootstrap code:*

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/typography/#responsive-typography

Comment: than you, I'll try that

Comment: Boostrap code should be the way to go, ideally, but some phones have a high pixel density. Mine is 1440px and the min width for large devices is set at 1200px. Go figure

Comment: the code you suggested works well, thank you. I will have to apply it to every div but that's ok

Comment: @AnastasiaIonas nice that it work's. Would you mark my answer as correct? Would be helpful for me too :)

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at the [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) in bootstrap.If you are targeting the desktop , the min width should be 970px (col-md-).

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 970px) {
body {
        font-size: 50% !important;
}
}
```

It will be better practice to use other unit rather than % value for font size

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. I guess something overrides it. I thought that I should remove all the '!important' tags related to font-size from the code, and it still doesn't work. I will paste the code up, maybe someone can see something I don't.

Comment: If your code still not working the please check the stylesheet hierarchy . Include stylesheet after bootstrap.